# jq: create object from another nested object

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the following json file

```
{
  "iter_1": {
    "rv_0": "rv_0",
    "rv_1": "rv_1",
    "rv_2": "rv_2",
    "rv_3": "rv_3",
    "rv_4": "rv_4",
    "rv_5": "rv_5",
    "rv_6": "rv_6",
    "rv_7": "rv_7",
    "rv_8": "rv_8",
    "rv_9": "rv_9",
    "rv_10": "rv_10",
    "rv_11": "rv_11",
    "rv_12": "rv_12",
    "rv_13": "rv_13",
    "rv_14": "rv_14",
    "rv_15": "rv_15"
  },
  "iter_2": {
    "rv_0": "rv_1",
    "rv_1": "rv_2",
    "rv_2": "rv_4",
    "rv_3": "rv_6",
    "rv_4": "rv_8",
    "rv_5": "rv_11",
    "rv_6": "rv_13",
    "rv_7": "rv_14"
  },
  "iter_4": {
    "rv_0": "rv_1",
    "rv_1": "rv_6",
    "rv_2": "rv_8",
    "rv_3": "rv_14"
  },
  "iter_8": {
    "rv_0": "rv_1",
    "rv_1": "rv_14"
  },
  "iter_16": {
    "rv_0": "rv_1"
  }
}
```

and I want to create a new object where the keys are top level keys (iter_n) and the value of each key is an array of the nested values. In other words, they value for `iter_2` is an array containing `[rv_1, rv_2...,rv_14]`. Is it possible to do this in jq ?

Here's what I tried so far :

```
 jq -c '{(. | keys[] as $k | $k) : (. | .iter_1)}'
```

Ideally, I'd like to use `$k` in the value part of object construction. From what I understand, the scoping rules of jq doesn't allow this. Is this true ? Are there other ways (in jq) to create the object I want ?

Comment: Could you provide a sample output, say for `iter_1` based on your example.

Comment: @devang It would be [rv_0, rv_,...rv_15]. Your answer below works great.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map_values`:

```
jq 'map_values([.[]])' file.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, here's the `jq`

```
to_entries | map({ "\(.key)": .value | to_entries | map(.value) }) | add
```

with output -

````
[
  {
    "iter_1": [
      "rv_0",
      "rv_1",
      "rv_2",
      "rv_3",
      "rv_4",
      "rv_5",
      "rv_6",
      "rv_7",
      "rv_8",
      "rv_9",
      "rv_10",
      "rv_11",
      "rv_12",
      "rv_13",
      "rv_14",
      "rv_15"
    ]
  },
  {
    "iter_2": [
      "rv_0",
      "rv_1",
      "rv_2",
      "rv_3",
      "rv_4",
      "rv_5",
      "rv_6",
      "rv_7"
    ]
  },
  {
    "iter_4": [
      "rv_0",
      "rv_1",
      "rv_2",
      "rv_3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "iter_8": [
      "rv_0",
      "rv_1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "iter_16": [
      "rv_0"
    ]
  }
]```
````

Comment: This purported solution does not meet the requirement that the `value for iter_2 is an array containing [rv_1, rv_2...,rv_14]`.

Comment: @peak Thank you for pointing it out. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
map_values([.[]])
```

Your question about jq variables is not so clear to me, but is apparently irrelevant here. Note, though, that `keys` sorts the key names.